# MySQL automaticly delete duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I want to display all data from the function below, however whenever the function is called, MySQL only returns one row if there are duplicates. What is the problem with my SQL Query?

```
$sql_response1 = "SELECT *
                    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tests_answers A, ".TABLE_PREFIX."tests_results R, ".TABLE_PREFIX."members M 
                    WHERE A.question_id=".$q_id." AND R.result_id=A.result_id AND R.final_score<>'' AND R.test_id=".$_GET['tid']." AND M.member_id =A.member_id AND M.member_id IN ($in_text)
                    GROUP BY A.answer ORDER BY A.answer";

            $result_responsed   = mysql_query($sql_response1, $db);

                while ($row_answer = mysql_fetch_array($result_responsed)) {

                    $x++;

                    $response_member = $row_answer['first_name'];
                    $response_answer = $row_answer['answer'];
                    $response_department =  $row_answer['department_name'];

                $x--;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(A.$x, $response_answer.' '.'('.$response_member.' - '.$response_department.')');
                     $x++;
                }
```

Let's say that the column `result_id` has two instances of the value *foo*, only one row will be returned. How do I show **ALL** results without MySQL truncating duplicate rows?

Comment: What do you think `GROUP BY` does?

Comment: i see.. does it effect duplication? i try to remove it

Comment: your problem description is not clear enough to understand what the actual problem is . Do you want to show only distinct records from a table? or while displaying the records, if you come across a duplicate record, you immediately want to execute a delete query to delete that record from the table?

Comment: @airi it will group - collapse together - rows with the same specified value, in this case `A.answer`.

Comment: @EdCottrell -- thanks.. can you answer my question.. my problems solve already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `GROUP BY` groups together - basically, collapses - all rows with the specified value in common. In this case, that means it will show only one row with a given value for `A.answer`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `GROUP BY` query which will return only one result and it will remove duplicates. If you're trying to sort the results use `ORDER BY` without using `GROUP BY` as well.

```
$sql_response1 = "SELECT *
                    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."tests_answers A, ".TABLE_PREFIX."tests_results R, ".TABLE_PREFIX."members M 
                    WHERE A.question_id=".$q_id." AND R.result_id=A.result_id AND R.final_score<>'' AND R.test_id=".$_GET['tid']." AND M.member_id =A.member_id AND M.member_id IN ($in_text)
                    ORDER BY A.answer";
```

For more background information on the GROUP BY function check out the informative page on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)